# Is there a preprocessor define that is defined if the compiler is MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

So I can do something like

```
#ifdef MSVC
//do compiler specific code here
#endif
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It's _MSC_VER. More info [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) and [at predef](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/#microsoft-visual-c).

But, be aware that some other compilers may also define it, e.g. Intel's C++ Compiler for Windows also defines _MSC_VER. If this is a concern, use `#if _MSC_VER && !__INTEL_COMPILER`.

Comment: +1 for the predef project reference. That is the first place to look when concerned about cross-platform definitions.

Answer (score 15):

Look at the list of [MSVC predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros). You'll find what you need.

`_MSC_VER` is probably a good one.

Answer (score 2):

`_MSC_VER` should fit your needs

Answer (score 2):

_MSC_VER is one such [predefined macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).